# mongodb express.js find object in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have this database "equipos" that looks like this:

```
    [   
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae4ea9f434d9b51dad68813"),
    "team_name" : "Alavés",
    "nombre_equipo_movil" : "ALA",
    "cantidad_integrantes" : 20,
    "partidos_jugados" : 29,
    "partidos_ganados" : 10,
    "partidos_empatados" : 1,
    "partidos_perdidos" : 18,
    "goles_a_favor" : 26,
    "goles_en_contra" : 45,
    "players" : [
            {
                    "dorsal" : 1,
                    "nombre_jugador" : "Fernando Pacheco",
                    "edad" : 25,
                    "nacionalidad" : "España",
                    "posicion" : "Portero",
                    "goles" : 0,
                    "asistencias" : 0,
                    "amarillas" : 4,
                    "rojas" : 1
            }
            ...
            ]
    ... 
    ]
```

So I want to check if there is a player with "dorsal" 1 in the team Alavés, and I'm doing this

```
db.equipos.findOne({"team_name": "Alavés" }, {"players": {$elemMatch: {"dorsal": 1l}}})
```

the problem is that the response to that query when there is no player with dorsal 1 is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ae4ea9f434d9b51dad68813") }
```

that being the id of the team. The problem is that when I'm sending that query with express like:

```
    dbo.collection("equipos").findOne(
        {"team_name": sReq.body.nombre_equipo }, {"players": {$elemMatch: {"dorsal": sReq.body.dorsal}}},
        function(err, res){
```

I cannot compare res to null to see if it couldn't find the player with that dorsal because I always get the ID of the team...

So how can I check that that player does not exist using that response?

Comment: What is the response when there is a player with that dorsal??

Comment: the same, but with the players attributes: { "_id" : ObjectId("5ae4ea9f434d9b51dad68813"), "players" : [ { "dorsal" : 1, "nombre_jugador" : "Fernando Pacheco", "edad" : 25, "nacionalidad" : "España", "posicion" : "Portero", "goles" : 0, "asistencias" : 0, "amarillas" : 4, "rojas" : 1 } ] }

Comment: Try with .....dorsal:parseInt(sReq.body.dorsal)....

Comment: Because typeof req.body.xxx==="string";but dorsal type:Number.So you must change string to number with parseInt method.

Comment: That was it, it's working now. Thank you so much! @ŞükSefHam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with .....dorsal:parseInt(sReq.body.dorsal).... – 
Because typeof req.body.xxx==="string";but dorsal type:Number.So you must change string to number with parseInt method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare `res` with `null`, you can compare `Object.keys(res).length == 1` for this situation. I really don't know why your query make that result. But I think this will help you.

```
if(Object.keys(res).length == 1) {
    console.log("No player found!");
} else {
    console.log("Hey there!");
}
```

Comment: It's always printing "Hey there", and I printed Object.keys(res).length and It's always 12

Comment: when there is no player with specific dorsal you said `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ae4ea9f434d9b51dad68813") }` is the output, an object with one key!

Comment: Check if the output has key `"players"` or not! @Iván

Comment: Yes, that is the output but from mongo console, I printed res.players and it shows all the players in that team

Comment: Why you don't use `.findOne( {"team_name": sReq.body.nombre_equipo }, {"players.dorsal": sReq.body.dorsal}` ??@Iván

Comment: You cant use --players.dorsal--@Saeed.Ataee.Because he/she has got one or more players.

Comment: if there are more than one player with `dorsal=1`, he must use `find` function with that conditions! @ŞükSefHam

Comment: Again and again i must write. You cant use find or findOne with players.dorsal.

Comment: Hmmm, it's interesting :D I did not know that! @ŞükSefHam

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose `findOne` method receives an optional second argument with the fields you want to select.

You should query like this:

```js
dbo.collection("equipos").findOne(
        {"team_name": sReq.body.nombre_equipo,
         "players": {$elemMatch: {"dorsal": sReq.body.dorsal}}
        }, function(err, res){
```

Notice both fields you want to query you pass as the first argument, and the second argument will be the callback, because you don't tell mongoose which fields to select in this case.